# I'm looking for an anime movie, made around 1980 - 2000

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am looking for an anime movie or series about a boy that travels with a girl on a submarine named Nautilus, some connection with Jules Verne novel.

Comment: Is there some sci-fi or fantasy element in the anime? If not, then it might be off-topic here. Please see here for more details: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: There's been lots of adaptations of 20,000 leagues; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7f9B1Emkpp4, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JljzW1ljIH4

Comment: Too many adaptations! Can you remember any details that would help to distinguish your movie from any others? For instance, a bit of dialog, or a memorable scene in the movie? Maybe the name of one of the characters?

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [*Nadia: The Secret of Blue Water*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadia:_The_Secret_of_Blue_Water) (1990-1991)? It was a TV series, but the first couple of episodes were broadcast together as a feature-length.

Although there's been [several](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7f9B1Emkpp4) animated [adaptation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JljzW1ljIH4) of [20,000 Leagues Under the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptations_of_Twenty_Thousand_Leagues_Under_the_Sea), this is the only one that meets both parts of the description in terms of age ***and*** key protagonists

> Set in an alternate universe 1889, the series centers on Nadia, a
> 14-year-old girl of unknown origins, and Jean, a young, warm-hearted
> French inventor. Early in the story, the two protagonists are chased
> by Grandis Granva, Sanson, and Hanson, a group of jewel thieves who
> pursue Nadia for the blue jeweled pendant she possesses. After being
> rescued by Captain Nemo and his submarine, the Nautilus, the jewel
> thieves and the young protagonists join forces and participate in the
> struggle against the Neo-Atlantean forces, who seek to dominate the
> world.
>
> In the process, Nadia and Jean save the world from violent domination
> by the Neo-Atlantean forces led by Gargoyle, explore worldly mysteries
> and the powers of the blue pendant, uncover Nadia's hidden family
> ties, and ultimately discover the secret origins of Nadia.